# How can I use Java to create a list of all the values from csv file that have the same row name

Tags: java, arrays, list, csv

[Excel file I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr35K.png)

I want to parse a csv file and extract the name, like 'chair' and then a list of each possible colour, so ['Blue','Green','Yellow']. How can I do this?

I have created a class Object, that has a 'String name' and a 'Listcolours'.

```
 CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(url.toURI()).getAbsolutePath()));
        Object<API> listings = new ArrayList<Object>();

            String [] line;
            List<String> colourList = new ArrayList<>();
           reader.readNext();
            while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                String name = line[0];
                String colour = line[1];
                colourList.add(operation);
                Object object = new Object(name,colourList);
                listings.add(object);
            }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: It doesn't, which is why I removed that tag.

Comment: *I  have created a class Object*  Not a good idea. That's the name of the Ur class. I would create a stream grouping operation giving you a map of groups

Comment: @g00se what do you mean by a 'stream grouping operation'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Hashmap with key as name of the item and value as list of colors available.

I hope below snippet will solve your problem. Good Luck!!

```
    HashMap<String,List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
    String [] line;
    reader.readNext();
    while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        String name = line[0];
        String colour = line[1];
        if(data.containsKey(name.toLowerCase())){
            data.get(name.toLowerCase()).add(colour.toLowerCase());
        }
        else{
            List<String> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
            colorList.add(colour.toLowerCase());
            data.put(name.toLowerCase(),colorList);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> @g00se what do you mean by a 'stream grouping operation'

I'll show you. Actually, in your case, since you're using a proper csv API, you can leverage that to create beans first, then do the grouping. Here's what I mean by stream grouping: we create a `Map<String, HouseholdObject>>` (yes that's my name for your entities - pity it's got the word 'object' in it, but never mind). That collects them into groups having the same name:

```
package com.technojeeves.opencsvbeans;

import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HouseholdParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<HouseholdObject> objects = new HouseholdParser().read(new File(args[0]));
            Map<String, List<HouseholdObject>> objectsGroupedByName = 
            objects.stream()
                .skip(1)
                .collect(groupingBy(HouseholdObject::getName));
            System.out.println("The following groups of household objects were found:");
            objectsGroupedByName.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .forEach(e -> {
                    System.out.println(e.getKey());
                    e.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .forEach(v -> System.out.printf("\t%s%n", v.getColour()));
                });


        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<HouseholdObject> read(File file) {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
            return new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader).withType(HouseholdObject.class).build().parse();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot read file: " + file.getName() + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the bean I made for it:

```
package com.technojeeves.opencsvbeans;

import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByPosition;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvCustomBindByPosition;
import com.opencsv.bean.AbstractBeanField;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvRecurse;

public class HouseholdObject {
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    private String name;
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private String colour;

    public HouseholdObject() {
    }

    public HouseholdObject(String name, String colour) {
        this.name = name;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return this.colour;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s=%s,%s=%s", "name", name, "colour", colour);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        HouseholdObject other = (HouseholdObject)o;
        return name.equals(other.name) && colour.equals(other.colour);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode() * colour.hashCode();
    }
}
```

And here's my output with your source CSV:

```
The following groups of household objects were found:
Table
     Purple
     Pink
Chair
     Blue
     Green
     Yellow
Door
     Yellow
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. It has a lot more lines of code than the solution provided by Akshay, would you say this is a better one?

Comment: I would say it's certainly useful to know how to bind csv data to domain objects. You would do that often in a professional context.